# What does this error mean in Redux - Toolkit?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I got the following error when using Redux-Toolkit, what does it mean?

```
   name:"ConditionError"
   message:"Aborted due to condition callback returning false."
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It means that an asyncThunk was not executed due to `condition`. If you are using RTK Query, that just means that another request was skipped because there was either already a request in flight or already a value in cache, so no request needs to be made. This is an internal rejection that RTK-Query uses to track component subscriptions and not an error.

Comment: thanks, can you point us to any Ref doc related to this, since throwing an error for cache hit seems weird

Comment: @STEEL Well, there are two options: "fulfilled" and "rejected". "rejected" does not only mean "error", it also means "condition not met" or "aborted". The "it means error" is only an assumption you have. For docs, see [dispatchConditionRejection](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#options)