# Any way to force refetch when using endpoint "initiate" function of redux-toolkit

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using:

```
dispatch(api.endpoints.getPosts.initiate(undefined))
```

But Im receiving following error inside redux:

```
name:"ConditionError"
message:"Aborted due to condition callback returning false."
```

I found the meaning of this error at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69789058/what-does-this-error-mean-in-redux-toolkit):

> It means that an asyncThunk was not executed due to condition. If you
> are using RTK Query, that just means that another request was skipped
> because there was either already a request in flight or already a
> value in cache, so no request needs to be made. This is an internal
> rejection that RTK-Query uses to track component subscriptions and not
> an error.

But is there any way to force the refetch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution. You should use `{forceRefetch: true}` option:

```
dispatch(api.endpoints.getPosts.initiate(undefined, {forceRefetch: true}))
```